# In AVCaptureSession the audio is not recording

Tags: ios, swift

In App, I wanted to capture two videos like one after the other, for this I have used  AVCaptureSession. Here I'm able to capture both the videos but not able to record audio for first video.

Below is the my code,

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import AVKit

class NewViewController: UIViewController, AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate {

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    var deviceOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    let captureSessionReaction = AVCaptureSession()
    var previewLayer : CALayer!
    var captureDeviceReaction:AVCaptureDevice!
    var captureAudioReaction :AVCaptureDevice!
    let videoFileOutputReaction = AVCaptureMovieFileOutput()
    var timer: Timer?
    var timer2: Timer?
    var timer3: Timer?
    var timeSec = 0
    var timeMin = 0
    var count = 0
    var captureChange : String!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 15.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.displayTimer), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer?.invalidate()
        timer2 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 20.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.displayTimer2), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        timer3 = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 35.0, target: self, selector: #selector(self.displayTimer3), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        captureChange = "reaction"
        prepareCamera()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func prepareCamera(){


            let inputs = captureSessionReaction.inputs as! [AVCaptureInput]
            for oldInput:AVCaptureInput in inputs {
                captureSessionReaction.removeInput(oldInput)
            }
            captureSessionReaction.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetHigh
            let devices = AVCaptureDevice.devices()
            var captureDeviceVideoFound: Bool = false
            var captureDeviceAudioFound:Bool = false
            for device in devices! {
                if ((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)) {
                    if((device as AnyObject).position == AVCaptureDevicePosition.front) {
                        captureDeviceReaction = device as? AVCaptureDevice
                        if captureDeviceReaction != nil {

                            captureDeviceVideoFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if((device as AnyObject).hasMediaType(AVMediaTypeAudio)){
                    print("Capture device audio init")
                    captureAudioReaction = device as? AVCaptureDevice //initialize audio
                    captureDeviceAudioFound = true
                }
            }
            if(captureDeviceAudioFound && captureDeviceVideoFound){
                startCaptureSession()
            }


           }

    func startCaptureSession(){
        do {



                captureSessionReaction.beginConfiguration()
                try captureSessionReaction.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureDeviceReaction))
                try captureSessionReaction.addInput(AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: captureAudioReaction))

            captureSessionReaction.commitConfiguration()

                let previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSessionReaction)
                previewLayer?.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill

                self.previewLayer = previewLayer

                self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
                //self.previewLayer.frame = self.captureSessionView.frame

                //self.previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: screenSize.height)
                self.previewLayer.frame = CGRect(x:0 , y: (screenSize.height - screenSize.height/3)-80, width: screenSize.width/2-50, height: screenSize.height/3)
                self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)

                captureSessionReaction.startRunning()



            videoStart()
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("error \(error)")
        }
    }

    func videoStart()  {



        let recordingDelegate:AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate? = self as AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate
        // self.captureSession.addOutput(videoFileOutput)

            if captureSessionReaction.canAddOutput(videoFileOutputReaction) {
                captureSessionReaction.addOutput(videoFileOutputReaction)
                let connection = videoFileOutputReaction.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

                if (connection?.isVideoOrientationSupported)! {
                    print("adding isVideoOrientationSupported")
                    connection?.videoOrientation = deviceOrientation
                }
                print("adding canAddOutput")
            }
            if captureChange == "reaction"{
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("reactionOutput.mp4")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.videoFileOutputReaction.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate:recordingDelegate)
                // self.isRecording=true
            }
        }

            else{
            let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
            let filePath = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("responseOutput.mp4")
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.videoFileOutputReaction.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: filePath, recordingDelegate:recordingDelegate)
                // self.isRecording=true
            }
        }

        }





    func displayTimer(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("displayTimer")

        self.videoFileOutputReaction.stopRecording()


        captureSessionReaction.removeOutput(videoFileOutputReaction)



    }
    func displayTimer2(_ timer: Timer) {
        print("displayTimer2")

captureChange = "react"
         self.prepareCamera()


    }

    func displayTimer3(_ timer: Timer) {

        print("displayTimer3")
               self.videoFileOutputReaction.stopRecording()
        captureSessionReaction.removeOutput(videoFileOutputReaction)


    }
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt fileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!) {


        print("didStartRecordingToOutputFileAt \(fileURL.relativePath) ")
        return
    }

    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCaptureFileOutput!, didFinishRecordingToOutputFileAt outputFileURL: URL!, fromConnections connections: [Any]!, error: Error!) {
        print("Out put path \(outputFileURL.relativePath)")


        UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.relativePath, self, nil, nil)
    }
}
```

If anyone had solution for this, please help me.

Comment: have you add required permission?

Comment: Ya, I have added required permission.